# OperationalError in django-friendship

Tags: django

What's the cause of this error from django-friendship?

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Please include the traceback in your question instead of posting a screenshot. Text is easier for other users to read and search.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error `No such table friendship_friend` because you haven't created the database tables yet. As the django-friendship app doesn't have any migrations, you could try creating migrations for the app and then running them.

```
./manage.py makemigrations friendship
./manage.py migrate
```

If that doesn't work, you could try syncdb.

```
./manage.py syncdb
```

Note the django-friendship says its tested with the 1.7 beta, so I don't know whether it works with Django 1.8 at all.